# How do I use JQuery to hide a div on click again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clicker").click(function() {
        $(".show_this").show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Using the script above I am able to show .show_this on clicking #clicker but on clicking #clicker again i want to hide it.  How can I tweak my code to do that?

I did some research and it seemed that by using `e.preventDefault();` I would be able to achieve that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clicker").click(function(e) {
        $(".show_this").toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ruGvV/1)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use `toggle();`

```
$(".show_this").toggle();
```

This will toggle every time, so if it is hidden it will show it and vice versa

**Api Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle**

Also `event.preventDefault();` will not be able to do this, though it is useful if the `.show-this` is a anchor tag because it will prevent the default action and that is to follow the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clicker").click(function(e) {  // call the event variable 'e' first here
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".show_this").toggle();            
    });
});
```